# Are Windows apps in 32-bit and 64-bit folders the same

Tags: windows, iis

I need to Install and Manage IIS on my 64-bit Windows 2008 server through the command prompt.

To install IIS & configure the required packages for IIS, I need to use `PKGMGR.EXE`

and to manage my website, create App pools, I need to use `APPCMD.exe`

Now, both `PKGMGR.EXE` and `APPCMD.EXE` are avaialble in both `c:/windows/system32/ and c:/windows/syswow64` folders.

1) Are both these applications in both these folders exactly same or is there any difference?

2) Will there be any problems if I install use both these Apps from System32 bit folder on my 64 bit OS?

Answer (score 1):

There are not the same, any programs under `syswow64` are 32bit binaries, anything under `system32` are 64bit binaries.

They usually have the exact same functionality but may affect either 32bit or 64bit parts of the OS.

The programs in `syswow64` are usually for backwards compatibility. A 32bit version of IIS will be installed here to run 32bit worker processes.

For installation and configuration you should always use the `system32` 64bit versions.

In case of `appcmd.exe` it shouldn't make a difference anyways, but I'm not sure about a 32bit `PKGMGR.EXE` having access to `system32`

Always use the programs in `c:/windows/system32/`